# Solve: $f(x+\frac{1}{y}) + f(x-\frac{1}{y}) = 2f(x).f(\frac{1}{y})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Here i have one functional equation:
If $$f(x+\frac{1}{y}) + f(x-\frac{1}{y}) = 2f(x)\cdot f(\tfrac{1}{y})\text{ for all x},y\in\mathbb{R}-{0}$$ and $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ , then find the value of $f(4)$.

Comment: I'd start by substituting $z=1/y$ to get the less weird-looking equation $f(x+z)+f(x-z)=2f(x)f(z)$.

Comment: Taking $\frac{1}{y}=x$, we get $f(2x)+f(0)=2f(x)f(x)$.
But taking $\frac{-1}{y}=x$, we get $f(0)+f(2x)=2f(x)f(-x)$.
Combining, we get $2f(x)f(x)=2f(x)f(-x)$.
Hence if $f(x)\neq 0$, then $f(x)=f(-x)$.  But if $f(a)=0$, we substitute $-a$ for $x$ to conclude that either $f(-a)=0$ or $f(-a)=f(a)=0$.  Hence $f(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Try eliminating a value for example Y from the equation

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, $f(x)$ is symmetric.  Set $a=f(1), b=f(2), c=f(3), d=f(4)$.  Then we have the following four equations:

$$d+f(0)=2b^2$$
$$d+b=2ac$$
$$c+a=2ab$$
$$b+f(0)=2a^2$$

This has two solutions according to [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Bd%2B1%2F2%3D2*b%5E2%2Cd%2Bb%3D2*a*c%2Cc%2Ba%3D2*a*b%2C+b%2B1%2F2%3D2*a%5E2%7D); in both solutions $d=-\frac{1}{2}$.  Finding them by hand doesn't seem too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

following Rahul's comment.

$f(x + z) + f(x-z) = 2f(x)f(z)$

take $x=z\neq 0$,

$f(2x) = 2f(x)^2 - 1/2$

$f(3x) + f(x) = 2f(x)f(2x) = 4f(x)^3 - f(x)$

thus

$f(3x) = 4f(x)^3 - 2f(x)$

and

$f(4x) + f(2x) = 2f(3x)f(x) = 2(4f(x)^3 - 2f(x))f(x) = 8 f(x)^4 - 4f(x)^2$

denote $f(x)$ as $f$ for short.

$f(4x) = 8f^4 - 4f^2 - (2f^2 - 1/2) = 8f^4 - 6f^2 + 1/2$

also

$f(4x) = 2f(2x)^2 - 1/2 = 2(2f^2 - 1/2)^2 - 1/2 = 2(4f^4 + 1/4 - 2f^2) - 1/2 = 8f^4 - 4f^2$

then $2f^2 = 1/2$, $f^2 = 1/4$, $f(x) = 1/2$ or $f(x) = -1/2$. for any $x\neq 0$.

which leads to $f(2x) = 0$ for any $x\neq 0$, contradiction. $f$ does not exist.

Answer (score -3):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos x$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: Was having similiar thoughts... but I think the answer is an integer

Comment: Well there may be more than one solution and mine is certainly one of them. I don't see why the answer must be an integer unless you impose this condition in your question.

Comment: it does not satisfy, I think. since your function is continuous, take $x=z = 0$ you got $f(0) = 1$ or $f(0) = 0$...

Comment: If you set $f(x)= C\cos x$, then the functional equation shows that $C=1$. But $\cos x$ does not satisfy $f(0) =  \frac 12$.